# after excution of a batch file a zero is placed in cmd

Tags: batch-file

my bat file content is :

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pabc.123 olm2 < q.sql
```

this is the content of my bat file, olm2 is the name of database, after execution of bat file:-

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pabc.123 olm2  0<q.sql
```

Query is executed but a zero is placed after my database name

hep it out

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't append the zero to your database name. It belongs to the redirection (`<`)

When redirecting in- or output, there are several streams:

0 = STDIN (Standard In), usually keyboard
1 = STDOUT (Standard Out), usually screen
2 = STDERR (Standard Error), usually screen.

When redirecting from a file (`<file`) the default is `0`.

Although you can omit it, the echoed command line will contain it.

Comment: @manoj - ??? Why do you think you need 0 deleted? `<q.sql` is shorthand for `0<q.sql`, and functionally identical. As Stephan already said, the 0 will always be present when the command is echoed, regardless whether you physically placed it in the file.