# Batch write command output to file - ghost character

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm trying to write a small batch (nothing fancy), but I'm facing a quite disturbing problem.
I need to write something to a file, and then read the content.

Here's an extract of the code:

```
SET CONNECTION=Local Area Connection    
SET TEMPFILE=c:\tempnetsh.txt

netsh interface show interface name="%CONNECTION%" > %TEMPFILE%
```

So you see, I try to write the result of this netsh command to my temporary file.
The problem is that when it runs, it does not execute

```
netsh interface show interface name="Local Area Connection" > c:\tempnetsh.txt
```

but

```
netsh interface show interface name="Local Area Connection" 1> c:\tempnetsh.txt
```

And the problem is that stupid "1", that comes from nowhere...

Any hint?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24801841/2152082. Same principle.

Comment: The one is always there but normally hidden when typed, in a batch cmd adds it to the line it displays. It is file handle 1, the screen (0=keyboard, 2=error). Your code works here to redirect. However the data from netsh is crap and bizzare. Can't explain that.

Answer (score 2):

`>` is effectively an abbreviation of `1>` from the days when redirection did not distinguish between destination devices (stdout and stderr).

The `1` merely means stdout as distinct from `stderr.` It has no effect on the output data that's redirected from the command.